# How do I set a public array length from user input?

Tags: c#, arrays, variables, input, structure

I set the variable CarsVar for firstInput() method to use and I want to call CarsVar AFTER it's modified by user input and set it to the new public variable 'Car' to set the length of the other variables. It causes and error because it sets the array length before it gets modified :(

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            firstInput();
            Input();  //A method to call all of the input first from the user.
            Calculate();
            Display();
        }

        public static int CarsVar; //Is for the number of cars that will be inputted.

        public static void firstInput()
        {
            Console.Write("How many cars? : ");
            
            string CarsINP = Console.ReadLine();
            while (!int.TryParse(CarsINP, out CarsVar)) //Is used to loop when input is in wrong format/doesn't match variable type int
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("Wrong Input Format. Try Again!");
                Console.Write("How many cars? : ");
                CarsINP = Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        public static int Cars = CarsVar;
        public static string[] carReg = new string[Cars]; //Placed after the input to set the other array lengths to = no. of cars
        public static float[] carSpeed = new float[Cars];
        public static bool[] carRegis = new bool[Cars];
        public static int[] carCosts = new int[Cars];
```

Comment: Arrays can't be resized, new ones must be recreated. IMHO don't create a set of parallel arrays, define a new class / struct and create an array / list of those.

Answer (score 0):

It appears you may be misinterpreting when variables are “initialized.” In this particular case, the code is assigning the size of the array “before” the variable used as the size is given a value.

Using the posted code, the lines…

```
public static int CarsVar; 
public static int Cars = CarsVar;
public static string[] carReg = new string[Cars]; 
public static float[] carSpeed = new float[Cars];
public static bool[] carRegis = new bool[Cars];
public static int[] carCosts = new int[Cars];
```

All of the above lines of code are executed “BEFORE” the `firstInput` method is called. This means that the array sizes will be zero (0) since `CarVar` has not yet been given a value. This means `Cars` also has no value. And when used as an array size will lead to an array of size 0.

Since, `CarsVar` is not set until “AFTER” the `firstInput` method is called, then you will need to set the array sizes “AFTER” the `firstInput` method has been called.

Therefore, one way to fix this is shown below. The variables are “declared” globally however they are not “initialized.” Then after the call to the `firstInput` method, the variables are “initialized.” Now the array sizes should be the value input by the user.

```
public static int CarsVar;
public static int Cars;
public static string[] carReg; 
public static float[] carSpeed;
public static bool[] carRegis;
public static int[] carCosts;


static void Main(string[] args) {
  firstInput();
  Cars = CarsVar;
  carReg = new string[Cars]; 
  carSpeed = new float[Cars];
  carRegis = new bool[Cars];
  carCosts = new int[Cars];
  Input();  
  Calculate();
  Display();
}
```

Comment: Ohh, I see how it works. Thank you so muchh !! :)